# Tell application "Microsoft Outlook" not working after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I have two Macs.  The AppleScript code below runs on one Mac ("Mac 1"), but not on the other ("Mac 2").  Mac 1 is running Snow Leopard, where Mac 2 was upgraded to Yosemite, and the AppleScript below no longer runs.

---

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set NewMail to make new outgoing message with properties{content:"Hello Ashlie, <br><br>I hope you are having a wonderful day. I wanted to send a quick note to thank you for signing up on our real estate website. I'm confident I know of or can easily find a property fitting your criteria. Are you looking to buy a home in San Diego?", subject:"A quick note to thank you"}
    make new to recipient at NewMail with properties{email address:{address:"example@example.com"}}
    open NewMail
    activate NewMail
end tell
```

---

Comment: I just tried your script and it executed as expected using OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 and MS Outlook for Mac 2011 with latest updates.  What type of error are you getting?